# Why does returning a mismatched type from a `match` block actually work?

Tags: rust, match

Rust is a strictly typed language. Yet, It does work when we return mismatched type from `match` block.

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;
fn main() {
    let n = 56; // just  typical variable to compare with
    let o = 56; // just  typical variable to compare with
    let a: i32 = match n.cmp(&o) { // using match to bind a's value which is an i32
        Ordering::Greater => 1,
        Ordering::Equal => { // however, is still works if I return an empty tuple though a is a type of i32
            println!("Equal");
            return ();
        },
        Ordering::Less => 3,
    };

    println!("{a}");
}
```

Comment: These two are not equal. When you do `return ()`, this `()` is not the result of the `match`. It's the result of `main`. `println!("{a}")` won't happen in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`Greater` and `Less` will assign an integer to `a` but `Equal` won't assign anything because `return` will leave immediately the function.

The compiler knows that and it won't complain about this branch of `match` not providing the same type as the other branches in order to initialise `a`.

Here, the current function is `main()`, it does not return anything (i.e. it implicitly returns `()`), then the compiler finds that this `return ()` statement is correct to exit the function.

When running your example, you should see that the last `println!()` does not happen in the `Equal` case.